# Custom contact form variables not being shown in email template if input marked as disabled

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, forms, contact-us

I have a custom contact form on the product view, so a customer can ask a question for a specific product. In the form I have a hidden text field with the current URL, so we know which product the question is for.

I've given the field the name producturl ...

```
$currentUrl     = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();

<input name="producturl" id="producturl" title="<?php echo $this->__('Product URL') ?>" value="<?php echo $currentUrl; ?>" class="input-text disabled" type="text" disabled />
```

I would expect the Email Template to output this field using

```
{{var data.producturl}}
```

since all other fields seem to work this way. Here is the Email Template:

```
Name: {{var data.name}} E-Mail-Adresse: {{var data.email}} Telefon: {{var data.telephone}} Bemerkungen: {{var data.comment}}  Produkt: {{var data.producturl}}
```

**Everything seems to be working, the email is sent and all the info is given out in the template apart from the producturl field. Can anyone give me a reason as to why this is?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is weird, but I have found out that a form field that is marked as 'disabled' will not be output in the $data.

Changing the input field from

```
<input name="producturl" id="producturl" title="<?php echo $this->__('Product URL') ?>" value="<?php echo $currentUrl; ?>" class="input-text disabled" type="text" disabled />
```

to

```
<input name="producturl" id="producturl" title="<?php echo $this->__('Product URL') ?>" value="<?php echo $currentUrl; ?>" class="input-text disabled" type="text" />
```

made the value appear in the email template.

Maybe this will be helpful for others.